# Symfony buildForm: place checkbox input inside label tags

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, formbuilder, symfony5

I have a form made with buildForm in symfony 5.3

One of the form fields is a checkbox, the 'active' one. This is the code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // some other fields
        ->add('active')
    ;
}
```

formBuilder is printing the checkbox like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="extract_ac_configuration_active">Active</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="extract_ac_configuration_active" name="extract_ac_configuration[active]" value="1">
</div>
```

But because I want the label to be clickable without need of javascript, and because the css framework I'm using, I need it to be rendered as

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="extract_ac_configuration_active" name="extract_ac_configuration">
    <span>active</span>
</label>
```

How can I change the way that checkbox is rendered through buildForm to the one I need?

Comment: How are you rendering the field? Using ```{{ form_row() }}``` ?

Comment: In controller `$this->renderForm('route_to/edit.html.twig', [
            'extract_ac_configuration' => $extractAcConfiguration,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);` and in the form.html.twig `{{ form_widget(form) }}` is the default way when you make a `php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud`

Comment: Ok then you must explode the rendering of the form. Check the answer i will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exactly have this result :

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="extract_ac_configuration_active" name="extract_ac_configuration">
    <span>active</span>
</label>
```

You must explode the form rendering. Instead of rendering globally like this :

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

you must do it like this :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

<label>
    {{ form_widget(form.active) }}
    <span>active</span>
</label>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Nice, it works, Thanks.  But only one detail. Now the checkbox is rendered as the first field, and I want it the last one, or at least in the position it was before.

Comment: For this, i think you must render other fields manually one by one. Just like you did for active field.

Just notice that ```{{ form_label(form.field) }}``` will print the label while ```{{ form_widget(form.field) }}``` will print the input.

Comment: Yes, I realize that I should render all the fields one by one, using the `{{ form_row(form.field) }}`then everything will be on this place. I must thank you once again. I've just found the documentation that explains it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html