# Symfony 6 Form make render all fields first, then render ones I need to edit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Hey guys so in my symfony form, i'm having a small issue regarding rendering, I want only to do a small change in a form, so it renders all fields first then renders the ones I edit.

But the thing is that I wanted to do this for multiple entities, like I have this as _form.twig.html

So I didn't want to render manually all, as the fields rendered by symfony already work fine.
I'm including the form with the entity and it's working, although the rendering is not how I want,

Save Button and Enabled Checkbox is at start of the form...
I'm thinking I might need some loop through all form widgets and I can't find how to do this in docs

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<h5 class="card-title activator">Edit {{ entity.id }}</h5>

<button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <label>
            {{ form_widget(form.enabled) }}
            <span>Enabled</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I need this because for some reason the form_widget for Enabled CheckboxType is not working correctly, so I wanted to edit the field through the form as I'm not sure what I need to do within the Type to make it render like this twig.

This question is based on [Symfony buildForm: place checkbox input inside label tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440190/symfony-buildform-place-checkbox-input-inside-label-tags)

It's almost same, but as said I don't want to render all fields manually, to avoid doing a twig template for each form I have, which are almost all the same thing, but differ names of labels. The issue is within comments too of that question too, as checkbox is being rendered first, but in his case he just did manually.